# PHP file download empty

Tags: php

Please help, this code downloads file but file is empty(0byte) but inside the folder its 1mb.

```
function dowloadbooks($id){
$allbooks ="SELECT * FROM books_table WHERE books_id = '$id' ";
$result=$this->conn->query($allbooks);
$row = array();

if($result->num_rows >0){ 

while($res = $result->fetch_assoc()){

$row = $res['book_upload'];
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .$row.'');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($row));
readfile($row); 
} 
} 
return $row;
}
```

Comment: Is it true that $res['book_upload'] is a "filename" of a file containing the data, or it is the data which you want the downloaded file to contain ? I ask this because you are using readfile in your code so I want to confirm

Comment: Due to the injection flaw, and the fact that you're not checking the file path, anyone can use this script to download any file off your entire server.  (Well, anything PHP has access to anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you break your problem into smaller chunks:

Your file does not exist most likely or you are using the wrong path relative to your script. When I modify your example to use an existing file and exclude DB functionality, the file downloads correctly with no errors:

```
dowloadbooks();
function dowloadbooks(){

    $row = 'c:/ExistingFile.png';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .$row.'');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($row));
readfile($row); 
return $row;
}
```

Let's try the same example with non existing file:

```
    //error_reporting(0);
dowloadbooks();
function dowloadbooks(){

    $row = 'c:/NonExistingFile.png';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .$row.'');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($row));
readfile($row); 
return $row;
}
```

I get two errors:

```
PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for c:/NonExistingFile.png in test.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  readfile(c:/NonExistingFile.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in test.php on line 14
```

But when I disable the error reporting with `error_reporting(0)`, suddenly the file is downloading with zero size!!!

### Conclusion:

Try displaying the file path first or/and enable errors with `error_reporting(-1)` - you should see where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks buddy sorted it long ago but the path was truly the issue.